# Can the EU package aid through the IMF in exchange of political favors?

Tags: european-union, egypt, international-monetary-fund

> “European and some Gulf countries are trying to provide economic aid
> in order for Egypt to play a strong role in the humanitarian crisis,”
> Giuseppe Dentice, head of the MENA desk at the Centre for
> International Studies, told TNA.

> The EU has already accelerated a financial aid package to Egypt aimed
> at preventing a surge of migrants from Egypt, as the nation continues
> to grapple with an economic crisis, with many EU states fearing the
> war in Gaza could produce a new wave of refugees.

> **The Gaza crisis comes at a time when Egypt is negotiating a larger
> financial package from the IMF to help with its economic crisis.
> President Sisi also faces presidential elections in December.**

https://www.newarab.com/analysis/egypt-pushing-back-against-israels-gaza-refugee-plans

Can the EU package aid through the IMF in exchange of political favors? Since the IMF is an international organization, and other countries like China are members of the organization, I am guessing it's not possible, but I think Europe and America holds the majority of the shares, so I was wondering if it was possible to do this through the IMF. I am guessing they're going to just take money from the EU own budget instead, but this excerpt make it sound like they can and might do it through the IMF.

Comment: EU aid and IMF deals are distinct. IMF usually only lends money, while aid is usually given for charitable purposes. But yes, IMF packages are often given only after political concessions are made to it.